# How can I scroll pyqt5 calendar widget by weeks and not by months?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5, pyside6

I have a Pyqt5 app that utilizes a QCalendarWidget
I need to be able to scroll the widget weekly
It seems the only behavior I can get is to scroll the pages by months
Is there a way to to that?
Thanks, Elad

Comment: QCalendarWidget just shows months, the fact that you can see days before or after the current month is just an added feature for UX purposes. If you want to scroll by week, you need to create a custom widget.

Comment: Thanks! I'll get on it